# Pass Swift variables to JavaScript in a web view

Tags: javascript, swift, webview

My problem is that I want to pass two variables from a web view  to Javascript to the same method but it won't work. I don't get the reason.

The statement is:

```
 webView.evaluateJavaScript("saveData(\(userID, username))", completionHandler: nil)
```

Where the variables is userID and user name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to build a string that contains the two values, you need:

```
"saveData(\(userID), \(username))"
```

This will give something like:

```
saveData(12345, Sara)
```

You might need quotes around the at least the name so do:

```
"saveData(\(userID), '\(username)')"
```

This will give you:

```
saveData(12345, 'Sara')
```

I don't know Javascript so adjust those quotes as needed.